# Swift date components incorrect return of date day number

Tags: swift, date

I need to obtain a date from some variable values
So I specify year, month and day and I need a Date as return
Doing the following works except for the day because it return the day input - 1

```
let todayDate: Date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date.from(year: 2022, month: 09, day: 05)!)
print("today date = \(todayDate)")

extension Date {
        
        static func from(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> Date? {
            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.year = year
            dateComponents.month = month
            dateComponents.day = day
            return calendar.date(from: dateComponents) ?? nil
        }
    }
```

And the output is

```
today date = 2022-09-04 22:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Are you living in a country with 2h difference with UTC? Meaning that when `2022-09-04 22:00:00 +0000` is in GMT+0, in your localtion, it's midnight already, so it's the next day?

Comment: Probably yes, do you have a suggestion on how to avoid this problem? Because I need to calculate the day without the time this is why I added startOfDay

Comment: In my country is 5.50 pm but always return 22:00:00

Comment: Time is relative. When you input `2022-9-4`, what do you want to get back? A `Date` object that represents September 4 where the client currently is, where the server is, or something universal like GMT? All 3 will give you different `Date` objects and depending on the time of day, they could display different days themselves.

Comment: I input 2022 09 05 and I expect the date object returned would be 2022-09-05 not 2022-09-04

Comment: But this is what people are trying to tell you, `2022-09-04 22:00:00 +0000` is the 5th in _your_ time zone.

Comment: Try printing using this command instead, `print(todayDate.description(with: .current))`

Comment: Don't `print` dates, you get always UTC regardless of your time zone. `2022-09-04 22:00:00 +0000` and `2022-09-05 00:00:00 +0200` is exactly the same point in time. Use a date formatter to convert the date to a string representation then you'll get what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date and time can be a bit tricky. The `Date` struct stores a point in time relative to `GMT`. If you print it it will show exactly that.

Solution:

Don´t use print, use a proper `Dateformatter`. To illustrate what I mean use this in a playground:

```
let date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
print(date)
//2022-09-03 22:00:00 +0000
// when it is 4.th of september 00:00 in my timezone (+- Daylight saving) it is this time in GMT

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss"

print(formatter.string(from: date))
//04 09 2022 00:00:00
// this is the time in my timezone
```

So the issue here is not that it has the wrong time, it is just not presented in the correct time zone.